# Cannot import the sql file to the phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to upload the SQL file to phpMyAdmin. Unfortunately, I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '23,7611748,'handling startet via WP Cron','2021-07-30
> 02:15:11','2021-07-30 04:1' at line 1

I think it is because of the incorrect SQL compatibility mode or character set of the file during the import. How do I detect which one I should specify? Or is the issue not here?

Comment: There's not enough info for us to help with this yet.

Comment: What else should I provide?